# Loading a scene, using Application.LoadLevel

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a basic Unity scene with a character, and then another scene with a UI button, so that when I press this button, the basic scene is loaded:

```
public void startSimulation()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("mainScene");
}
```

The basic scene has a directional light that is always there by default, but when I press the button in Editor mode, the scene loads in a dark state.

This does **not** happen when I build. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the upper section of the Game window, there are some buttons, used for activate/deactivate light, sound, etc...Maybe you have just clicked one of them by error.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about this, so I learned something. But it doesn't solve this issue. When I open the basic scene, it is lit up. When I run the app with this basic scene open, it is lit up too. Only when I open the button scene and press the button, the basic scene is loaded "BUT" in a dark state. Even in the build, it all works fine, so i cannot figure out why in the editor, the button press loads the scene in a dark mode...

Comment: Seems it is a Unity5 bug: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/application-loadlevel-application-loadedlevel-resets-level-but-causes-light-intensity-to-change.308248

Comment: Hi Ricardo.  Thanks for your comment.  A bit of relief, knowing that it is a bug.  I thought I was being silly...  Cheers